# Shared variable between thread not modified

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an instance of Data in my class Server shared between 2 thread :

```
public class Server{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Data data = new Data();
    Thread t1=new Thread(new ClientService(data));
    Thread t2=new Thread(new PromoService(data));
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

Here are relevant parts of my classes :

```
public class ClientService implements Runnable{

  public Data data;


  public ClientService(Data data){

    this.data = data;
  }

  public void run(){
    this.data.newClient(t[1],Integer.parseInt(t[2]),Integer.parseInt(pass),ia);
}
```

Here, let's suppose t is a String array, ia an InetAdress and pass a string ( i have removed the part of code where these variables were created to make it more simple ).

```
public class Data implements Serializable{ 

public ArrayList<ClientData> listClient;

public Data(){
  this.listClient = new ArrayList<ClientData>();
}

public synchronized boolean newClient(String id,int port,int pass,InetAddress ia){

  for(int i = 0 ; i < listClient.size(); i ++){
    if(listClient.get(i).id.equals(id) ){ 
      return false;
    }
  }
  ClientData ncl = new ClientData(port,ia,id,pass);
  this.listClient.add(ncl);
  return true;
}
```

Before the newClient(), listClient contains nothing ( size = 0 ). After the call i try to print listClient and the size has become 1, but the contained element is null. I don't understand : is something hindering the new ClientData object to be added to this shared variable ?
When i try, i make sure this thread is the only one accesing or modifying the instance at this time.

Comment: This is just an idea, but try declaring `listClient` as `final` or `volatile`. It could be that the compiler is doing something funny, but I doubt it The synchronization ought to ensure good behavior on its own. Also, the thread which accesses `listClient` afterwards (to check what's in it) needs to synchronize on `data` too. `synchronized (data) { System.out.println(data.listClient); }`

Comment: I just added this line and it works, thanks a lot ! However i don't understand why it changes anything if i'm sure nobody else is modyfing it at the moment

Comment: The old value of null could still be saved in registers instead of being loaded from ram. To reduce the risk of running into unexpected problems like this I would try not to do any synchronization manually but instead use an instance of `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference` to save my shared variables in.

Comment: where and how do you _read_ the `listClient`value?

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, synchronization is required when you read from `listClient` because it forces memory consistency between threads. In absence of synchronization, some thread `A` can make a change to some variable `x` and another thread `B` is not required to see that change to `x`. Synchronization forces threads to see the changes to shared memory.

Technically this is because the CPU has a local cache which it stores variables in temporarily. Synchronization forces the CPU to load variables from main memory, as opposed to looking at the cache which could be out of date.

So, `synchronized (data) { /* look at what's in data.listClient */ }` forces the reader thread to see whatever changes to `listClient` were made during the synchronized method `newClient`. (A synchronized instance method is the same as `synchronized (this)`.)

From your description it sounds like the reader thread was seeing that the list's `size` got incremented but never saw the change to the backing array.